# Web service error HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I am following a simple webservice tutorial and can't seem to interact with the Java code. I suspect my web.xml has an error but I'm not sure. There are no obvious errors and the index.jsp is server without any problems.

So, when I'm running it on the server, it opens index.jsp and I then try the following urls, but I'm getting 'HTTP 404 Errors'

- http://localhost:8080/RestApi/ - works, shows html page
- http://localhost:8080/RestApi/rest - http 404 error
- http://localhost:8080/RestApi/rest/hello - http 404 error
- http://localhost:8080/RestApi/rest/hello/somevalue - http 404 error

Here is what i have
Dynamic web project with jersey libs imported. 
A note on this - I got an error for class not found and saw that I had to use Glassfish.org... instead of the com.sun one, don't know why, but there ya go.
[image]

My web.xml is as follows. No errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RestApi</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>Rest Web Services App by me</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>exampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>exampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My java class is as follows. No errors.

```
package com.rest.example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg){
        String output = "Welcome to the world of Rest : "+msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old Jersey 1.x property

```
com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
```

For Jersey 2.x it should be

```
jersey.config.server.provider.packages
```

As a general rule, *anything* where you see `com.sun.jersey` is for Jersey 1.x and `org.glassfish.jersey` is for 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

try:

> http://localhost:8080/rest/RestApi/hello

check [my case](https://github.com/no7dw/javaCourse/tree/master/WebSerivce)

the rule seems like this: /{url-pattern}/{project}/{path}

I run my case with jetty

[another example](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/04/create-restful-web-servicesjax-rs-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

the above issue can occur due to following reasons :

1. First check the name of your application deployed in the webapps folder of the tomcat, whether it is matching your url or not that is giving 404.But in the above case, as it is showing the welcome page, then it is not the concern here.
2. Check the url pattern mention in the web.xml as it must be the same as in the url you are hitting.

> `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

3. Third thing to check is that the path defined in the rest class with @Path annotation.
4. Check the web.xml for following entries if you are using jersey jars 2.x as suggested above by @Paul Samsotha

> ```
> <servlet> 
>       <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
>       <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
>
>       <init-param> 
>          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
>          <param-value>com.pizzeria</param-value> 
>       </init-param> 
>    </servlet>
> ```

5. There may be a possibility to get this error when your server has been up without any errors but the context of your application hasn't. You can check it in the logs.For further information please refer this Link ---> [404 error due to SEVERE: Context [/example] startup failed due to previous errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345945/severe-context-example-startup-failed-due-to-previous-errors/51453464#51453464)